# How to properly use store.* in conjunction with storyboard

Tags: coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I'm adding in-app payments to my storyboard-based game using Corona's 'store' library. Since I have multiple scenes where different purchases can be made, I wanted to get some thoughts on where to call store.init() and where to puts its callback.

For example, If the user buys in-game currency from the "town" scene, I'll need to update the view to reflect the new amount of currency. If they buy a sword from the "battle" scene, I'll need to update the battle view with the new sword. What's the best approach to getting scene-specific logic into the main transaction callback?

One approach I can think of is to register custom event listeners on a global display object (e.g. the storyboard scene) that listen for purchase events, and dispatch events from the main callback. But making the scene object global feels dangerous. Another is to call store.init() every time a purchase is made and pass in a different callback for each type of purchase (or at least for each scene). However I'm not sure that's even kosher.

Neither of these seems like a great design to me. Any better ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I have done is a wrapper class around corona's store.
I use this wrapper to store products, purchase them, etc (and also handle platform-specific differences).

My wrapper class is initialized once at the beginning of the game, top of main.lua, then I just have to call myStore:purchase(id, callback) to purchase a product on a specific page.

For the view / events, page, you can use in your store:

```
Runtime:dispatchEvent({name='productBought', id=productId})
```

And all your view objects can have:

```
Runtime:addEventListener( 'productBought', callback)
```

Then you will have to check in your callback that it's the proper product id etc..
If you would like to make the event less generic, just use something like:

On the store side:

```
Runtime:dispatchEvent({name='productBought'..productId})
```

On the view side:

```
Runtime:addEventListener( 'productBought'..productId, callback)
```

That way only this specific object will receive this :)